# What does this "(base)" mean in my terminal prompt?

Tags: command-line

```
(base) fedaa@fedaa-Satellite-L50-B:~$ cd molecules/
```

What does this `(base)` mean in my terminal prompt?

I just found it and I have no idea what it refers to.

Comment: It might e.g. be your current git branch or something like that. Can you type `echo "$PS1"` in your terminal and add the output to your question? That shows the template of your prompt.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

1. It is most likely that the last program or script that you invoked didn't correctly ended with a new line character.

   Here is a simple example:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   printf "test"
   ```

   Copy this content into your editor and save it as a file called test.sh

   Then make it an executable

   ```
   chmod 755 test.sh
   ```

   and invoke it with

   ```
   ./test.sh
   ```

   The output will be

   ```
   fedaa@fedaa-Satellite-L50-B:~$./test.sh
   test fedaa@fedaa-Satellite-L50-B:~$
   ```

   If you add a `\n` (new line character)

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   printf "who\n"
   ```

   the result will be

   ```
   fedaa@fedaa-Satellite-L50-B:~$./test.sh
   test
   fedaa@fedaa-Satellite-L50-B:~$
   ```
2. In case you are using anaconda or the conda environment, look at this link

   https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/getting-started.html

   To see a list of all your environments, type:

   ```
   conda info --envs
   ```

   A list of environments appears, similar to the following:

   ```
   conda environments:

       base           /home/username/Anaconda3
       snowflakes   * /home/username/Anaconda3/envs/snowflakes
   ```

   In that case `(base)` marks you are using the default anaconda environment.

   To deactivate the environment, type

   ```
    source deactivate
   ```

   After recent changes in the functioning of conda package manager , the use of "source deactivate " is being depreciated and support for this command might  be ended.

   However

   ```
   conda deactivate
   ```

   is more suitable to be used.

   In **newer anaconda releases** simply type this conda command in your shell:

   ```
    conda config --set auto_activate_base False
   ```

Comment: To activate it back ```conda activate```

Comment: I have this `(base)` thing going on. Can it be harmful in anyway, or can I continue as usual?

Comment: This can be problematic when you install packages as they would be installed in `base`  virtual environment. To deactivate is use `conda config --set changeps1 False`. You can alternatively change it in your `/.bashrc` or set your own virtual env to get activated.

Comment: Still a great answer in 2023, worked perfectly.